# WP8 Xaml Have an icon in the Application Bar show up with alert

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm relatively new to the development for the Windows Phone, and currently i am trying to see what i can do with the application bar in the bottom.

I currently have 3 items in the bar, and now i would like to "highlight" one of the items when the app (Asynchronous) finds there is a new item.

Kinda like you have with your email, that it shows on the same icon that you have a new mail..

kinda like this:
http://easystepstowp.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Custom-Icon-Design-Pretty-Office-9-Email-alert.ico

Can i place the "exclamation" on top of an existing icon or should i replace the icon with the one that shows the alert?

What is best practice in this case? solve this in the xaml, or the xaml.cs...

Thanks in advance for any insights anyone has to share!

Comment: I don't think you can modify the icon assigned to an appbar button, you have to assign another one. And since in WP8 the appbar is not true XAML element (it is provided by the OS) you will have to do that in code

Comment: Thanks! That helps me along the way!